# Android: How to change DatePickerDialog colors in Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.MinWidth?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-datepicker

I'm using Api 14 and the only way i found to hide the calendar view from my DataPickerDialog is using Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.MinWidth when I create it.
But now i'm not able to change the colors of text and header.

[Image of DatePickerDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHUDF.png)

How to change the blue color and the ok/cancel buttons?

Code of styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/backtext</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="DatePickerTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.MinWidth">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/border</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/border</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/backtext</item>
</style>
```

DatePickerDialog creation code:

```
    private void InitDatePicker() {
            Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            //android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_MinWidth
            //

            datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.DatePickerTheme,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    dtVenc.setText(new SimpleDateFormat().format(newDate.getTime()));
                }
            }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            HideDayButton(datePickerDialog.getDatePicker());
            datePickerDialog.setTitle("Vencimento");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

you should use `headerBackground` instead `android:headerBackground` and same for `android:textColorHighlight` remove `android`

this should work

Comment: Removing android causes a complier error "attribute not found"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
<style name="abirStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
<style name="abirStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:background">@null</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```